# Spring MVC: The JsonView And ResponseBodyAdvice Beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a `ResponseBodyAdvice` bean which wraps the returning objects from  rest controller with a specific form:

```
public class Response<T> {
    private T data; //the data is from the rest controller
    private int code;
    private String message;

}

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ResponseAdviceConfig implements ResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body instanceof Response) {
            return body;
        } else {
            return new Response<>(body);
        }
    }
}

@Data
public class User {

    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String account;

    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String avatar;

    private String realname;

    @JsonView(SummaryView.class)
    private String nickname;

    private String password;


    public interface SummaryView {
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/user")
public class UserAPI {
    @GetMapping("/follows/list")
    @JsonView(User.SummaryView.class)
    public List<User> followsList(@RequestParam String account){
        return userService.followsList(account);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the `@JsonView` annotated method in controller doesn't work anymore and the final response just a empty object `{}`. I guess that this `ResponseBodyAdvice` bean may conflict with the internal `JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice`. I debuged but without result.

Comment: I have the same problem.. -.-'
Did you solved this?